# Multi-page record creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

puts 'newbie question'

I have an account sign-up that spans multiple pages, but I'm not exactly wrapping my head around creating a new instance that is tied to a database but only adds to the database if all pages are completed.

I have three actions:

```
def index
@ticket = Ticket.new
end

def signup_a
end

def signup_b
end
```

The index page only collects a single text field, then passes that to populate the field in signup_a, then to b, which is where the record is finally added to the database.  How do I go from passing the variable from index to A to B in a Ticket object without actually adding it to the DB?

Edit---

I think I got tripped up that the line

```
if @order.save
```

actually saves the object...I thought it just performed a check.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep it in the session and save it in the database once all the steps are complete .